# i want to connect to SSMS database from eclipse but it throws SQLserverException

Tags: java, database

I want to connect to SSMS database from eclipse. when compiler reaches to `DriverManager.getConnection(url)` line it throws error.I enable TCP/IP also but it giving error.

```
try{            
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        System.out.println("driver loaded successfully");
        connection= DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\MSSQLSERVER;user=sa;password=coder182");
        System.out.println("Connection created successfully");
        connection.setAutoCommit( autoCommit);
        statement=connection.createStatement();

        String query ="insert into User_information(name, card_no,amount)" + "values ('"+name+"','"+card_no+"', '"+amount+"');";
        statement.executeUpdate(query);

        System.out.println(query);                      
    }catch(Throwable th){
        th.printStackTrace();
    }           
}
```

Error:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection to the
>   host localhost, named instance mssqlserver failed. Error:
>   "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out". Verify the
>   server and instance names and check that no firewall is blocking UDP
>   traffic to port 1434.  For SQL Server 2005 or later, verify that the
>   SQL Server Browser Service is running on the host.

I want to connect it to database.

Answer (score 1):

- open SQL Server Configuration Manager
- SQl Server Network Configuration
- protocols for MSSQLSERVER
- TCP/IP(Must be enabled already or enable it)
- (Double Click)
- IP Addresss
- scroll down to IPALL
- Enter port number 1433 or 1434 and leave dynamic ports empty and apply setting and restart your service

And you must specify databaseName you want to connect

```
"jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;instance=MSSQLSERVER;databaseName=name_of_database;user=sa;password=your_password;"
```

Mark answer as accepted if issue resolved

Answer (score 0):

If "MSSQLSERVER" is the name of the database then try

```
 "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=MSSQLSERVER;user=sa;password=coder182"
```

if it is the name of the instance try

```
 "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;instanceName=MSSQLSERVER;user=sa;password=coder182"
```

and of course verify that the server is running and using port 1434